# Proving that if $B^1_\delta(0) \subset B_1^2(0)$ and $B_\epsilon^2(0)\subset B_1^1(0)$ then the norms are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to prove the following proposition:

Let $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ two norms on X, and suppose there exist $\delta, \epsilon>0$ such that $B^1_\delta(0) \subset B_1^2(0)$ and $B_\epsilon^2(0)\subset B_1^1(0)$. Then $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ are equivalent.

We know that two norms $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ on a vector space are equivalent if there exist constants $c_1, c_2$ such that

$$c_1||x||_1 \le ||x||_2 \le c_2||x||_1$$

but the thing I have with the hypotheses of the proposition is that $||x||_{1}<\delta, ||x||_{2}<1$ for $x \in B^1_\delta(0)$, and for $x_{1} \in B_\epsilon^2(0)$ we have $||x_{1}||_{2}<\epsilon,||x_{1}||_{1}<1$.

So I can't figure out how to combine this inequalities to get the desired condition.

**The thing is that any of the equalities that I have give me a >, if we notice we only get <**
Can someone help me with this problem please?. Thanks a lot in advance :).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For any $x$, consider $z = \frac{\delta x}{2 ||x||_1}$.What do you know about that $||z||_1$? Notice that this will imply $||z||_2 < 1$. Now, unravel that statement by substituting $z$ for $\frac{\delta x}{2 ||x||_1}$. This should yield you one side of the inequality. Other should be rather similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but I don't understand the notation of $\delta_{x}$, or Am I missing something?

Comment: And the other thing, How can I manipulate $z$ since I don't know how the norms are?, Well and what about $x=0$?

Comment: $\delta x$ is just $\delta $ times $x$. You don't need to know the norms, just follow the inequalities. I'm saying unravel what $||z||_2 < 1$ means by using the definition of $z$. The case where $x=0$ must be taken care of separately, but this is a trivial case since your desired inequality always holds for $x=0$.

Comment: Ok, let me check :)

Comment: Thanks I have got $(\delta/2)||x||_{2}<||x||_{1} $, So the other side should be as the same shape?

Comment: The thing is that any of the equalities that I have give me a $>$, if we notice we only get $<$

Comment: What can be done in that case?

Comment: I don't quite follow. If you do the same with $\epsilon$, you'll get an inequality similar to the one you have before, but with 1 swapped with 2, and $\delta$ swapped with $\epsilon$.

Comment: Yes, but the upper bound?, because I only got the lower bound :(

Comment: It's the same thing ? If you have $(\delta / 2) ||x||_2 < ||x||_1$  and $\epsilon / 2 ||x||_1 <  ||x||_2$ then put them together to get $ (\delta /2) ||x||_2 < ||x||_1 < (2 / \epsilon ) ||x||_2$

Comment: Ok :) I see, I have proven that this is a equivalent relation so it ia done right ?